# Is payment by credit or cash an usecase?

Tags: uml

I'm working on an usecase diagram. The customer can pay through credit card or cash or check. I know I should mention them in diagram. But are they three separate main usecases that should be listed under usecases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, what is or is not a use case depends on the use case philosophy you are applying. The person who taught the UML class that I attended made it very clear that in his opinion, a use case can only be something that an actor *wants* to do.

As such, "Entering a Password" can never be a use case, because a user doesn't want to enter a password. Entering a password can just be a step within a use case, such as "Check the Account Balance".

I'd see paying as a very similar case. A customer doesn't want to pay for its own sake; a user pays because it's part of a bigger process, which is a use case.

Comment: so wireless customer choosing a plan between Individual and family plan is not two different usecases?

Comment: @BadSniper: If you go by the philosophy I described (which is totally your choice; I'm not saying this one's better than others), then "Choosing a Plan" is not a use case at all; "Using a Plan" may be one, though.

Comment: so choosing a plan between two is a step within the usecase "viewing or paying for plan"?

Comment: No, choosing, viewing and paying for a plan would be steps in the use case "Using a Plan".

Comment: the software I've to design doesn't include using or something like that. It has to do with enrolling into a plan and PDA selection. That's it. In that case my prior comment is right?

Comment: @BadSniper: For all I've read about UML and in particular UML Use Cases, there mostly is no *right* or *wrong*. You are using UML correctly when it enhances the mutual understanding about how the product is supposed to work among all parties involved in the design and development process.

Answer (score 1):

You can model a payment use case and then create three extending use cases,  one for each payment method

Answer (score 0):

Only if the system you are modeling responds differently to different methods of payment.

Comment: that means..In a wireless plan customer can select family or individual plans. Does that mean they are two different usecases under plans?

Comment: Yes, if you are modeling the carrier behavior, then the use case is different, because the carrier responds differently to different plans.